# iOS - Objective-C - How Do I Pull Files From Google Drive? (Preferably Documents)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to know how I can pull a file from **Google Drive**, specifically a **document file**.  I'd also like a way to display this document on an application.  Does anyone know a way that this can be achieved?

I've heard something about a **Google Drive API**, but I've never really figured out how it works.

If anyone could tell me how I can do this, that'd be great.  **Keep the questions simple as I'm quite new with Objective-C and iOS.**

I'm currently using **XCode** to build this application.

Answer (score -2):

You can integrat the google drive to your app,for that you need the help of google Drive API for iOS.

> Below link is the introduction to the API's
>
> [Introduction to the Google Drive Platform for iOS](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/intro)
>
> [Drive API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/)

[Google Drive Integration in iOS app](http://www.innofied.com/google-drive-integration-in-ios-apps/) this tutorial  helps you for integration.